# Python file search using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a file that has many lines. Each line starts with {"id": followed by the id number in quotes. (i.e {"id": "106"). I am trying to use regex to search the whole document line by line and print the lines that match 5 different id values. To do this I made a list with the ids and want to iterate through the list only matching lines that start with {"id": "(id number from list)". I am really confused on how to do this. Here is what I have so far:

```
f= "bdata.txt"    
statids = ["85", "106", "140", "172" , "337"] 
x= re.findall('{"id":', statids, 'f')
for line in open(file):
            print(x)
```

The error code I keep getting is: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

I need to whole line to be matched so I can split it and put it into a class.

Any advice? Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you're not married to regex, a simple `if line.startswith('{"id":') and int(line[6:]) in statids:`

Comment: You'll also want to open your file for reading properly - you may want to google Python3's `open()`

Comment: Is this a json file? Why not just load the file as a dictionary and filter by id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the id from the line using the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/mD5rYW/1), `^\{\"id\": \"(\d+)\"` where the value of group#1 will give you the id. Then, you can check if the id is present in `statids`.

**Demo:**

```
import re

statids = ["85", "106", "140", "172", "337"]

with open("bdata.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        search = re.search('^\{\"id\": \"(\d+)\"', line)
        if search:
            id = search.group(1)
            if id in statids:
                print(line.rstrip())
```

For the following sample content in the file:

```
{"id": "100" hello
{"id": "106" world
{"id": "2" hi
{"id": "85" bye
{"id": "10" ok
{"id": "140" good
{"id": "165" fine
{"id": "172" great
{"id": "337" morning
{"id": "16" evening
```

the output will be:

```
{"id": "106" world
{"id": "85" bye
{"id": "140" good
{"id": "172" great
{"id": "337" morning
```

Comment: That worked! So now how would I take those lines and insert them into a class? I only need part of the lines. I have the class created already.

Answer (score 0):

I the issue here is the way you're using re.findall, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) you have to pass a regular expression as the first argument and the string that you want to match the expression to as the second argument. In your case I think this is how you should do it:

```
pattern = f'id: ({"|".join(statsids)})'
with open(f) as file:
  for line in file:
      match = re.findall(pattern, line)
      print(match.group(0))
```

in the regex the pipe operator "|" works same as or so by joining all the ids as an string with | in between them will find all the cases where it matches one id or the other. the match.group line returns where it was found.